# Tensorflow. Cifar10 Multi-gpu example performs worse with more gpus

Tags: neural-network, tensorflow, distributed-computing

I have to test the distributed version of tensorflow across multiple gpus.

I run the Cifar-10 multi-gpu example on an AWS g2.8x EC2 instance.

Running time for 2000 steps of the cifar10_multi_gpu_train.py (code [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/models/image/cifar10/cifar10_multi_gpu_train.py)) was 427 seconds with 1 gpu (`flag num_gpu=1`). Afterwards the eval.py script returned precision @ 1 = 0.537.

With the same example running for the same number of steps (with one step being executed in parallel across all gpus), but using 4 gpus (`flag num_gpu=4`) running time was about `530` seconds and the `eval.py` script returned only a slightly higher precision @ 1 of 0.552 (maybe due to randomness in the computation?).

Why is the example performing worse with a higher number of gpus? I have used a very small number of steps for testing purposes and was expecting a much higher gain in precision using 4 gpus.
Did I miss something or made some basic mistakes?
Did someone else try the above example?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

The cifar10 example uses variables on CPU by default, which is what you need for a multi-GPU architecture. You may achieve about 1.5x speed up compared to a single GPU setup with 2 GPUs.

Your problem has to do with the Dual GPU architecture for Nvidia Tesla K80. It has a PCIe switch to communicate both GPU cards internally. It shall introduce an overhead on communication. See block diagram:
[image]

Comment: I encountered the same issue with 2 Nvidia Tesla K80s on GCP. I see how the dual architecture causes a lot of overhead for the internal GK210 GPUs. However, I was under the impression that we had two separate K80s (see print screen below): https://postimg.org/image/pitpneai9/ , do you think our setup is just a single K80 with GK210s?